# Release strategy for multiple Git feature branches being tested simultaneously

Tags: git, team-foundation-server, release-management

We have three environments: `Dev`, `UAT` and `Prod`. We use `TFS` to schedule releases of our `master` branch into `Dev` for our internal verification, then `UAT` for business verification, and of course finally to `Prod` once approved.

We've recently adopted a new lightweight Git branching strategy as follows:

`master` is *always* prod-ready. At any point `master` should be able to be deployed to production.

All *new* development is done in a separate feature (topic) branch as follows:

1. Create a new feature branch off `master`, call it `FeatureA`
2. Develop `FeatureA` until completion
3. Once `FeatureA` is finished, release it to `Dev`, and then `UAT`
4. Once the business signs off on `FeatureA` in `UAT`, it's considered prod-ready. Merge `FeatureA` into `master`, then deploy the new `master` branch to `Dev` then `UAT`. During the way, "smoke test" the branch in `UAT` to ensure the resulting merge into master didn't cause any unforeseen side-effects. Once smoke-tested, release to `Prod`.

The problem we're coming across right now is that we may have multiple features being developed in parallel, all of which could potentially need to be deployed to the test environment for verification at the same time. The approach we've taken to solving this problem is:

If `FeatureA` and `FeatureB` need to be in UAT at the same time, then:

1. Create a new branch, `FeatureAandB`, which will encompass both features
2. Merge `FeatureA` into `FeatureAandB`
3. Merge `FeatureB` into `FeatureAandB`
4. Release `FeatureAandB` to `Dev`, then `UAT`

The downside to this is that it's unlikely both `FeatureA` and `FeatureB` will be `UAT` verified at the same time. If `FeatureA` is verified and `FeatureB` is not, we need to release `FeatureA` to prod without `FeatureB`. What we've discussed in this scenario is to:

1. Merge `FeatureA` (not the joint branch, but just FeatureA) into `master`
2. Release `master` to `Dev`, then `UAT` for a quick smoke-test, and finally `Prod`
3. Once in prod, re-release just `FeatureB` to `Dev` then `UAT` so testing can continue.

The downside to this is that it directly impacts any testing for `FeatureB`, and potentially unwinds any work the testers have accomplished with `FeatureB`.

**How do you manage multiple features living simultaneously in each environment and being released potentially independent of one another?** We can mitigate the issue a little more if we have multiple environments, or turn-around UAT testing much quicker, but at the end of the day the same problem can exist.

I'm not opposed to hearing alternative branching strategies, either.

Comment: How often does this situation come up, and how long does it take `Dev` and `UAT` to test?

Comment: @mmathis historically, not very often, but we've recently dedicated more resources to this app and have several features being developed in parallel, so I anticipate this happening more frequently than in the past. As for length of time in UAT, that varies by the complexity of the feature and how involved testing must be, as well as the availability of the stakeholders requesting said feature (stakeholder of FeatureA isn't guaranteed to be the same as FeatureB, either).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ahh. Congratulations! You’ve destroyed one bottleneck and discovered the next one! Now it’s time to look at *actually* continuously integrating your code. As you’ve found out, it’s hard to continuously deliver when your code under dev isn’t being continuously integrated, but *how* do you make this work?

No more feature branches.

No. Seriously. No more feature branches.

It’s time to introduce [feature *toggles*](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/FeatureToggle.html) into your system. 
Instead of delivering new features by delivering code, you need to have complete control over when a feature is turned on for a given environment. 
In other words, you want to have environment specific configuration that turns features on and off. 
This decouples code releases from feature releases.

Comment: Potentially of interest would also be [branch by abstraction](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/BranchByAbstraction.html)

Comment: Oddly enough, this is what we had in place, and what we were trying to get away from with the main reason being "if the code isn't prod ready, it shouldn't go to prod, even behind a feature flag". This originally came from the results of an audit. However, the points you make are absolutely correct, we're attempting continuous delivery without continuous integration, which just doesn't work. Do you by chance have any resources on hand that could help educate myself around this process, and why it's actually the way to go, or how this doesn't violate any compliance concerns?

Comment: I have no idea what kind of regulations you have to deal with, so I really don’t know. Sorry.

Comment: What kind of audit?

Comment: Of course: SOX compliance. However, I may have spoken too soon when I brought that to your attention, as I believe we already satisfied their concerns by implementing an approval process from a non-dev before deployment to each of our environments. With that said, I think this is honestly the best approach, it really becomes a challenge of convincing the team and management. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: You’re welcome. Glad I could help. I would probably put some process around your configuration management. I’m sure that will help with compliance.

Answer (score 6):

Test features separately and in order, that's really the best way to do it. Usually whichever one is done first gets tested first, but business needs could change that priority. When `FeatureA` is accepted, it's merged into the main branch (`dev`, `UAT`, or `master` in your case, as applicable), that branch is merged into `FeatureB` and then feature B is tested. A is tested first, then B, then C, etc, with each feature branch getting updated as other features are tested and accepted.

By testing features separately, you keep the focus on one feature and one team is responsible for fixing any problems. There's a clear responsibility for keeping the code in a good state when handling merge conflicts (in this case, the `featureB` team needs to merge `dev` in and deal with any merge conflicts, ensuring that the code from `featureA` is maintained). Separate features also makes it easy to assign "blame" when a problem is discovered - not the "why did you break this" kind of blame, but the "this feature is causing a problem, remove it from `dev` until we can sort it out" kind of blame

If you're finding that a lot of `FeatureX` branches are spent waiting for testing or multiple branches are being completed at the same time, you can either break them up into smaller features, or allocate more resources for testing. Both approaches should decrease the time to test an individual branch.

Similar features that will be completed at the same time may best be developed on a single branch. That's kind of what you propose with the `FeatureAandB` branch, but in this case, they get accepted or rejected as one. If the features are not similar / related, though, test them separately.

Finally, make sure you're making use of any automation available, so teams aren't waiting on another team for anything. Most build servers can be set to build Pull Request branches, producing a `FeatureA+dev` build which can go to QA for acceptance and integration testing. The developer simply opens the PR (which also serves as a code review, if desired, and also serves to signal that the feature is ready for testing), and once QA signs off on it, completes it. This then merges the branch into `dev` automatically. Can do the same for `UAT` and `master`, creating PRs for merging `dev` into `UAT`, and `UAT` into `master`.

You may then be able to reduce the number of branches, and stick with `dev` and `master`, plus `featureX`. Get rid of `UAT`, as that role is essentially served by `dev`. Actual development is done on `featureX` and production is in `master`. Deploy new code whenever `master` is updated, or deploy whatever is in `master` whenever you want to release.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. Unfortunately our environment and way of business doesn't necessarily lend itself to sequential feature testing/ rollout. Our application is a monolith with multiple sub-applications it encompasses, each of which has a different set of stakeholders (or even multiple sets). Along with that, the stakeholders aren't always as quick at completing UAT as we'd like, while some others are. Holding up testing of one feature while another is being tested just won't go over well.

Comment: If your alternative is to test multiple features at the same time (`FeatureAandB`), testing takes twice as long. End result is the same, but testing them separately gives you additional benefits.

Comment: Well, not necessarily. If we deploy `FeatureAandB` in parallel, and they have two different sets of stakeholders, then they can be tested in parallel as well. The sequential testing you suggest really shines when `FeatureA` and `FeatureB` are both going to be tested by the same group.

Comment: To me this encourages long-lived branches, which increase risk and costs and decrease overall development velocity. Waterfall, in a way. It used to be the norm, but these days we have CI/CD - agile enabler and generally considered a superior development approach.

Comment: An underlying issue I can see here is that the testing is "too long", with respect to development. So making it is faster would clearly improve the overall process (which ever way you implement it, independent feature being best though). So, either add man power or automate as much as you can the testing part. If you automate enough testing, you can accept feature A before it is user tested (because nothing serious will be broken), not blocking feature B. Developing a proper test system is a long run, never ending, work. So start soon